# dnf, clear commands not working inside docker conatiner

Tags: docker, containers

Hi im trying to build a container with
base os- centos:8
container image- fedora:33
when i give a dnf install command it returns with a failure, so i went inside the container in interactive mode and tried to do a dnf install or clear but getting the same error

```
# dnf --help
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/dnf", line 57, in <module>
    from dnf.cli import main
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dnf/__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
    import dnf.base
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dnf/base.py", line 29, in <module>
    import libdnf.transaction
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/libdnf/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from . import conf
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/libdnf/conf.py", line 13, in <module>
    from . import _conf
ImportError: /lib64/libffi.so.6: rebuild shared object with IBT support enabled
```

How to rectify this error.

Comment: You wouldn't usually run package tools like this inside a running container, since anything you install will be lost as soon as the container exits.  Do you have a Dockerfile or other source code that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: FROM fedora:32
RUN ["dnf","install","-y","python3","numactl","which"]
.....

Answer (score 1):

I solved mine by just doing this:

```
yum groupinstall "Development Tools"
```

The dnf  worked and also the clear command.